# JS ajax - load more than one txt file in string - wrong order

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax request that loads text files.

path like:

```
media/img/NAME1/descI.txt
media/img/NAME2/descI.txt
```

url : `http://www.domain.com/media/img/"+sortTitles[i]+"/descI.txt`

That returns all txts in one div. but i don't want that. i want to place them content into different divs. e.g. desc1 in div1...

here is my code. -> `sortTitles[i]` loads the correct files.

```
    $.ajax({
  url: "http://www.domain.de/chat/media/titles.txt",
  dataType: "text",
  scriptCharset: "ISO-8859-1",
  success: function(cats) {

    sortTitles = cats.split('+++');
    Chatlength = sortTitles.length - 1;

    for (i = 2; i < Chatlength; i++) {

      catholder = document.createElement('div');
      catholder.setAttribute("id", "cat" + i + "");
      catholder.setAttribute("style", att1);

      element = document.getElementById("categories");
      element.appendChild(catholder);

      catheadwr = document.createElement('div');
      catheadwr.setAttribute("id", "headwr");
      catheadwr.setAttribute("style", att3);
      cathead = document.createElement('div');
      cathead.setAttribute("id", "head");
      cathead.setAttribute("onClick", "openshow('" + sortTitles[i] + "');");

      cath2 = document.createElement('h2');
      cath2.setAttribute("id", "h22");
      cath2.setAttribute("style", att2);

      cathimg = document.createElement('img');
      cathimg.setAttribute("id", "catbg");
      cathimg.setAttribute("src", "http://www.domain.com/media/img/" + sortTitles[i] + "/covr.jpg");

      catdesc = document.createElement('div');
      catdesc.setAttribute("id", "desc" + i + "");
      catdesc.setAttribute("style", attdesc);
      cath2text = document.createTextNode("#" + sortTitles[i] + "");

      element = document.getElementById("cat" + i + "");
      element.appendChild(catheadwr);
      catheadwr.appendChild(cathead);
      element.appendChild(catdesc);

      $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.domain.com/media/img/Mediathek/" + sortTitles[i] + "/descI.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
          i--;
          document.getElementById("desc" + i + "").innerHTML = data;

        }
      });

      cathead.appendChild(cath2);
      cathead.appendChild(cathimg);
      cath2.appendChild(cath2text);

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: there is a for function before that. AND i really don't know but "i" keeps ending at the length of the string and i can call the content of the txt files by substracting with i--. maybe i need to set i=0 again and count up for some reason. is the full code necessary?

Comment: Please format your code with proper 4-space indentation.  Thanks!